# Removed cookie from request adding custom headers

Tags: reactjs, ajax, axios

I want add a custom header to my ajax call with Axios

I code this:

```
serviceInterface.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.headers['x-zeus-app-id'] = 'CC';
        return request;
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

adding this line:

```
request.headers['x-zeus-app-id'] = 'CC';
```

the key 'x-zeus-app-id' is added to the request, but other keys, like cookie, is removed from headers.

any hint?

thanks.

Comment: I dont see any cookie is removed, https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-test-6ps4w9?file=/index.js:304-379 this is the code I tested in my local and axios adding the header and not dropping others, also I do not see any cookie.